# ie11 caching background images while changing styles

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I have a DIV which holds background images, and I change them by bootstrap carousel item change by passing data-bg attribute like below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg-holder" data-bg="bg-1">
  <div id="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-bg="bg-1">
      .... some slider content
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bg="bg-2">
      .... some slider content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
const bgHolder= document.querySelector(".bg-holder");
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  bgHolder.dataset.bg = e.relatedTarget.dataset.bg;
})
```

**CSS**

```
.bg-holder[data-bg="bg-1"] {
  background-image: url(image1.jpg)
}
.bg-holder[data-bg="bg-2"] {
  background-image: url(image2.jpg)
}
```

I set data-bg="bg-1" by default and then on every carousel change i pass the new data-bg value. it works great in all modern browsers except IE11 which do not refresh the images from css, and it keeps displaying the one i loaded by default. When I open developers tools and uncheck/check the declaration it displays the proper image. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I test in IE and reproduce the issue. As a workaround, you could set the `background-image` as inline style of `bg-holder` and change it on every carousel change according to `bg` value. The sample code is like below:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bg-holder" style="background-image: url(image1.jpg)">
  <div id="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-bg="bg-1">
      .... some slider content
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bg="bg-2">
      .... some slider content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    if (e.relatedTarget.dataset.bg == "bg-2") {
        $(".bg-holder").css("background-image", "url(image2.jpg)");
    }
    else {
        $(".bg-holder").css("background-image", "url(image1.jpg)");
    }
})
```

You could also check this [online demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yuzhou0602/57mnsbtL/4/) in IE 11.